# Recursive call to onActivityResult

Tags: android, recursion, android-intent, barcode-scanner

I am creating an app to scan a set number of barcodes.  I create an Intent for ZXing and call startActivityForResult.

Once the barcode is processed in onActivityResult, I call startActivityForResult using the Intent passed into onActivityResult.

This, unless I am mistaken, is a recursive call to onActivityResult.  There could be up to 30 barcodes.

Is this okay?  I would rather make direct API calls to ZXing, but I am having troubles finding examples.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a recursive call to `onActivityResult()` and should work just fine. It's not recursive because your `onActivityResult()` calls `startActivityForResult()` which returns right away and thus allows the `onActivityResult()` method to finish it's execution. If it didn't, then there would be no need for the `onActivityResult()` in the first place. You could just use the return value of `startActivityForResult()`.